# Keep my Navigation Drawer when starting a Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

So far I have had a `MainActivity` that swaps through Fragments. But I have implemented a `FragmentActivity` in order to use a `ViewPager` and swap through `Fragments` in one of my Drawer's section.

But when I click on my Drawer's item that creates the `ViewPager`, the Drawer disappears all together.

Here is how I start my `FragmentActivity`:

```
private Fragment checkFragment(int itemId) { // Checks what item the user has pressed and calls the right Fragment / Activity
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (itemId) {
        // HOME (If user clicks on HOME in Drawer)
        case R.id.nav_home:         
            fragment = new Home(); // Set Fragment to be used
            break;
        // STATS GENERAL (If user clicks on General Stats)
        case R.id.nav_stat_general:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, GeneralStatistics.class)); // Start the Fragment Activity
            fragment = null;
            break;     
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

And here is my `Fragment Activity` `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.statistics_general);

    mStatisticsPagerAdapter = new StatisticsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mStatisticsPagerAdapter);
}
```

How may I keep my Drawer even though I have gone from one Activity to another?

Comment: can I make you change the extent of the GeneralStatistics class to a fragment instead of activity ?

Comment: I tried that, changed the way I call the fragment in the first code snippet and yet the Drawer does not display

Comment: what you mean by snippet?

Comment: and the drawer should works at will by fragments, will you add your drawer code and the first fragment code

Answer (score 0):

To keep your Navigation Drawer. you must have to replace the viewpager content by another Fragment.

**From your code**

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, GeneralStatistics.class));
```

This line clearly shows that you are Intenting to another activity (not a Fragment which replaces your viewpager content)

I recommend you to take a look at this [Example](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/).

Answer (score 0):

Solution / work around to my problem:

I do not use an `ActivityFragment` anymore but simply a `Fragment` and replaced its `onCreate` with the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.statistics_general_vp, container, false);
    // No more setContentView

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mStatisticsPagerAdapter = new StatisticsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mStatisticsPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}
```